# Can we enable 1920 X 1200 HiDPI mode on OS X 10.9.2?

Tags: display, resolution, display-settings, macbook-pro-retina

with RDM, we can enable a number of displays such as the Retina 15" or Retina 13" to do the 1920X1080 HiDPI but with some screen area blacked out. Can we enable 1920 X 1200 by overriding some system files? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some more detail of how I did it on my Macbook Pro Retina 2012:

I was using RDM, but had no 1920x1200 HiDPI mode (the highest was 1920x1080).

I downloaded and installed SwitchResX. Then clicked "Color LCD", and "Custom Resolution". Then click the "+" icon and add in a new Scaled Resolution of 3840x2400:

[image]

Close SwitchResX and make sure it asks to save (you'll need to enter an Admin password). Then restart the Macbook.

Then RDM shows this in the menu:

[image]

Squint and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Jimmy Ying 'ayeying' (https://twitter.com/ayeying). He says, "I don't have the 13" Retina MacBook Pro anymore. All you need to do is add 3840x2400 in SwitchResX. This automatically enables 1920x1200 HiDPI."

So all we need to do is to manually install a 3840x2400 profile to the system (you can use SwitchResX or whatever you want).